# Web socket stops responding after awhile

Tags: c#, websocket, windows-services, slack, slack-api

I have a windows service that uses a websocket (from http://sta.github.io/websocket-sharp/) to conenct to Slack and monitor messages.

My connection code looks something like this:

```
ws = new WebSocket(connection.Url);

ws.OnMessage += async (sender, e) =>
{
    var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageFromSlack>(e.Data);
    if (msg.Type == "message" && msg.Text != null && msg.User != UserId)
    {
        if (userMatcher.IsMatch(msg.Text))
        {
            await ProcessDirectMessage(msg);
        }
        await ProcessMessage(msg);
    }
    if (msg.Type == "channel_joined")
    {
        await ChannelJoined(msg.ChannelModel.Id);
    }
};

ws.OnClose += (sender, e) =>
{
    var reason = e.Reason;
    var code = e.Code;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{code}:{reason}");
};

ws.Connect();
```

Basically it waits for a message and then if it's directed @ my bot, it'll call `ProcessDirectMessage` and if not it'll call `ProcessMessage`. The details of those functions are, I think, unimportant (they do some matching looking for key phrases and respond by sending a message back).

This all works fine. For a while. But after some period of time (usually more than a day), it just stops responding altogether. My `OnMessage` handler never gets hit. I thought that maybe what is happening is the websocket is getting closed on the server side, so I added the `OnClose` handler, but that never seems to get hit either.

Does anybody have an idea what might be happening here? Is there a way to keep the connection alive, or else reconnect it when it dies?

Comment: Did you confirure your websocket to send ping requests?

Comment: @Evk as far as I can tell, the library is supposed to take care of that itself. In so far as there doesn't appear to be a place to configure it.

Answer (score 3):

By the nature of TCP connection - the only reliable way to detect its gone is to write something to it. If you are just reading (waiting for data to arrive) - you can do that for a very long time while the other side is long time dead. That happens if that other side did not close connection gracefully (which involves an exchange of some TCP packets).

Web socket protocol defines special Ping frame, and corresponding Pong frame, which you should use to avoid situation described in the question. From time to time you should send `Ping` frame and wait (for a certain timeout) for server to respond with `Pong` frame. If it did not respond in given timeout - assume connection is dead and reconnect.

As far as I know - library you use does not automatically send ping requests on your behalf. However, it allows you to do that via `Ping` method.

You need to configure timeout with

```
ws.WaitTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

And then, from time to time (for example - when you did not receive any new messages in last X seconds), do:

```
bool isAlive = ws.Ping();
```

There is also boolean property which does the same:

```
bool isAlive = ws.IsAlive;
```

This is a blocking call (both of the above). It will return true if server replied with `Pong` during `ws.WaitTime` interval, and false otherwise. Then you can act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with that and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: I'd suggest to test by running your own websocket service in separate console app. It can send message to client every second, and then you can kill it in process explorer and observe the result.